# How do you know how to use twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find a complete document. For example, the `popover` effect([here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover)) will use a DOM's `data-origin-title` attribute as its own title, and `data-cotent` as its content:

```
$('#somedom').hover (->
    $(this).addClass("hover")
    $(this).attr("data-original-title","Location")
    $(this).attr("data-content":'The popover plugin provides a simple interface for adding popovers to your appli    cation. It extends the bootstrap-twipsy.js plugin, 
                so be sure to grab that file as well when including popovers in your project!')
    $(this).popover({})
    $(this).popover("show")
    ),->
        $(this).removeClass("hover")
```

Where to learn it? The offcial document doesn't have `data-origin-title` attribute. Neither in source code of `bootstrap-popover.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is right up there in the **Options** table. It grabs the `title` attribute for the title, and `data-content` for the content (3rd column). The `data-original-title` you see on the HTML is added by the plugin script after executing, ignore it.

The idea for this is that you already have the info on the HTML:

```
<div id="mything" title="My title=" data-content="Some text here">Test popover</div>
```

So your script only does this, you don't need to handle events:

```
$('#mything').popover()
```